# Polymer 2.0: use Polymer.dedupingMixin with typescript

Tags: typescript, polymer, polymer-2.x

Can you please help provide an example to implement Polymer mixin behavior in typescript?
I'm trying to write a Polymer mixin in typescript as below:

```js
export var testMixin = Polymer.dedupingMixin((superClass : (new ()=> Polymer.Element))=>
{
    return class extends superClass
    {
        ready()
        {
            super.ready();
            console.log("Test Mixin");
        }
    }
});
```

but the generated typescript definition is wired.

Generated typescript definition:

```
export var testMixin: (superClass: new () => Polymer.Element) => {
    new (): {
        ready(): void;
        accessKey: string;
        readonly children: HTMLCollection;
        contentEditable: string;
        readonly dataset: DOMStringMap;
        dir: string;
        draggable: boolean;
        hidden: boolean;
        hideFocus: boolean;
        innerText: string;
        readonly isContentEditable: boolean;
        lang: string;
```

-------------------------------------Updated.

I finally have the mixin in ts as below:

```
 export interface ocITestMixin
{
    property1: Object;   
}

export interface ocITestMixinConstructor
{
    new(...args: any[]): ocITestMixin;    
}

export var ocTestMixin =
    Polymer.dedupingMixin((superClass: (new () => Polymer.Element) & Polymer.decorators.ElementConstructor) =>
    {
        return class ocTestBehavior extends superClass
        {
            property1: Object;           

        } as ((new () => Polymer.Element) & Polymer.decorators.ElementConstructor & ocITestMixinConstructor);
    });
```

-------- the file to use this ocTestMixin

```
import { ocITestMixin, ocITestMixinConstructor } from 'ui';

export class ocZoomTextBox extends UI.ocTestMixin(Polymer.Element)
{
}
```

Comment: I'm also interested in this -- were you able to find a solution?

Comment: @Lange See my updated post. This is what I finally ends up with.